# Способы образования слов ''сначала'', ''повязано''

Tags: словообразование

Здравствуйте.

Выполняя тесты ЕГЭ, столкнулась с проблемой.

Вопрос: Из предложения надо выписать слово, образованное приставочно-суффиксальным способом. В ответах дано слово ''сначала''. Но в предложении, откуда нужно выписать слово, есть и другое слово: ''повязано''.

Хотелось бы узнать, слово ''повязано'' образовано приставочно-суффиксальным способом? Т.е. **по** - приставка, **вяз** - корень, **ан** - суффикс, **о** - окончание. А может, у этого слова есть окончание, поэтому оно не в счет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**повязано** - краткая форма от причастия *повязанный*, образованного от глагола *повязать* с помощью суфф. - НН-. Это суффиксальный способ.

**сначала** - образовано от сущ. *начало* с пом. приставки С- и суфф. -А - пристав.-суффиксальный.

Comment: А чем является л?

Comment: начал - корень

Comment: Спасибо!!!

Comment: 
Бэла Вартанова: А чем является л?===


Суффиксом. См. цепочку: НАЧА-ть -> НАЧА-Л-о -> С-НАЧАЛ-А.




Comment: slava1947 , т.е. здесь два суффикса?

Comment: slava1947,начал/о -корень начал, как в началь/н/ый. Когда-то разбиралось так: нача/льн/ый, потом произошло перераспределение. А слово МЫЛО Вы как разберёте - мы/л/о? тоже ведь от мы/ть.А правильно: мыл/о. А в словаре -онлайн ещё интересней: на/ча/л/о - вообще прошлый век. В современном языке сущ.начал/о; нача/ть; начин/а/ть

Comment: Людмила, да, в этом словаре смотрела. Там вообще говорится, что А - окончание. Там много ошибок.

Comment: Людмила:  "В современном языке сущ.начал/о."===


А какими из СОВРЕМЕННЫХ словарей это можно подтвердить?

Comment: там разбирает не человек, а робот, потому и ошибки

Comment: В бумажном Тихонове ("Словообразовательный словарь русского языка" в 2 т., М., 1990) словообразовательная цепочка у слова "сначала", как у меня в первом моём комментарии. Т. е. суффикс "л". В бумажном "Словаре-справочнике" (М., 1997) того же Тихонова -- С-НАЧ-А-Л-А. Что у него в более новом бумажном "Морфемно-орфографическом словаре" (про онлайн-версию которого Вы говорили) -- посмотрю завтра.

Comment: с/на/ча́/л/а, Тихонов А. Н. Морфемно-орфографический словарь: Около 100 000 слов / А. Н. Тихонов. — М.: АСТ: Астрель, 2002. — 704 с.

Comment: Да во всех по-разному.У Панова, Текучёва с/начал/а, У Потихи 1987 г.   с/нача/л/а. Но в этом же словаре : началь/н/ый(ср.начал/о).Это как понять-сначала не от сущ., а от глагола? началь/ник (ср.быть под началом). У Тихонова в словообразовательном словаре нача/ть-нача-л(о)- с-начал-а. Значит, тоже выделяет суффикс Л. Но всё это было давно. Цепочка верная, а вот современное состояние языка это не передаёт, идёт переосмысление морфем.Корень теперь и в глаголе связанный-нача-

Comment: Людмила, я с вами согласен. Я тоже считаю, что корень здесь связной. А у вас нет каких-н авторитетных словарей? Современных?

Answer (score 1):

Бэла, а Вам известно, что вопроса о способах словообразования, о котором Вы просите совета здесь, в тестах ЕГЭ в 2015 году нет, как и многих других вопросов, которые были в прошлом году?

Comment: Я и не собираюсь сдавать ЕГЭ. Я просто для себя решаю. Повышаю уровень. Мне не известно. Но я просмотрю ЕГЭ за 2015.

Comment: Людмила: "Значит, тоже выделяет суффикс Л. Но всё это было давно. Цепочка верная, а вот современное состояние языка это не передаёт, идёт переосмысление морфем."===


Людмила, но неужели же Вы не чувствуете родство слов НАЧАТЬ и НАЧАЛО? Почему в СОВРЕМЕННОМ языке "л" не суффикс?

Comment: Серж, современных нет, все 80-90-х годов. Новым вообще не верю,и Тихонову тоже, там уже не он, а кто-то правит, и такие ляпы случаются...В школе пользовались  Школьным грамматико-орфографическим словарём Панова и Текучёва, но с Потихой тоже бывали расхождения. А у Тихонова словообразовательный с его же морфемным расходится. По-моему, пошла безалаберность при печатании или перепечатывают со старых,а наука идёт вперёд.

Comment: Людмила: "а наука идёт вперёд."===

Ну так почему же Вы считаете, что с позиций СОВРЕМЕННОЙ науки "л" -- НЕ СУФФИКС?